# Computational Complexity of Multivariate Normal CDF

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, numerical-integration

I'm going to post this here also as per user suggestions since I feel like the root cause of the issue is more maths related than code related.

I'm working on a multivariate cross-entropy minimization model (for more details about it, see [this paper](http://www.systemicrisk.ac.uk/sites/default/files/downloads/publications/dp-74-web.pdf), pp. 32-33). It's purpose is to adjust a prior multivariate distribution (in this case, a gaussian normal) with information on marginals coming from real observations. The code at the end of the post represents my current implementation. The maths should have been correctly implemented following the paper guidelines, and I feel like the code cannot be optimized any further.

We can basically focus on the first `parfor` loop, which takes more than 80% of total runnining time. Here, cumulative probabilities are being computed over all the orthants of the multivariate density. The paper presents a bivariate example, but the model can be generalized for `N` entities. Therefore, the process has a time complexity of `2^N`. As long as the number of entities is less than or equal to `13`, everything is fast enough on my PC. With `20` entities, which is my current target, the model needs to run `mvncdf` over `1048576` combinations this litterally takes forever to finish.

Maybe big problems require big time and I reached a dead end. But I'm wondering if there are faster algorithms to perform this kind of computations. Maybe someone out there found a way to deal with this using a different algorithm that outperforms this "standard" way to go. Any suggestion is more than welcome. But, please, be gentle with me! Being more a coding geek than a stats guru, sometimes it's very difficult for me to figure out how to translate formulas into code... so I prefer to deal with pseudo-code snippets and/or numerical examples, if possible.

```
clc();
clear();

% DATA

pods = [0.015; 0.02; 0.013; 0.007; 0.054; 0.034; 0.009; 0.065; 0.029; 0.205];
dts = [2.1; 2; 2.2; 2.4; 1.5; 1.8; 2.3; 1.5; 1.8; 0.8];

% Test of time complexity:
% pods = [pods; pods];
% dts = [dts; dts];

n = numel(pods);
c = eye(n);

k = 2^n;
kh = k / 2;
offsets = ones(n,1);

% G / BOUNDS FOR 1

g1 = combn([0 1],n);
bounds_1 = zeros(k,1);

parfor i = 1:k
    g1_c = g1(i,:).';
    lb = min([(-Inf * ~g1_c) dts],[],2);
    ub = max([(Inf * g1_c) dts],[],2);

    bounds_1(i) = mvncdf2(c,lb,ub);
end

% G / BOUNDS FOR 2:N

g2 = repmat({zeros(kh,n)},n,1);
bounds_2 = zeros(n,kh);

for i = 2:k
    g1_c = g1(i,:);
    b = bounds_1(i);

    for j = 1:n
        if (g1_c(j) == 0)
            continue;
        end           
            
        offset_j = offsets(j);

        g2t_j = g2{j};
        g2t_j(offset_j,:) = g1_c;
        g2{j} = g2t_j;

        bounds_2(j,offset_j) = b;

        offsets(j) = offset_j + 1;
    end

end

% SOLUTION

options = optimset(optimset(@fsolve),'Display','iter','TolFun',1e-08,'TolX',1e-08);
cns = [1; pods];
x0 = zeros(size(pods,1)+1,1);
lm = fsolve(@(x)objective(x,n,g1,bounds_1,g2,bounds_2,cns),x0,options);

stop = 1;

% Objective function of the model.
function p = objective(x,n,g1,bounds_1,g2,bounds_2,cns)

    mu = x(1);
    lambda = x(2:end);

    p = zeros(n + 1,1);

    for i = 1:numel(bounds_1)
        p(1) = p(1) + exp(-g1(i,:) * lambda) * bounds_1(i);
    end

    for i = 1:n
        g2_k = g2{i,1};
        
        for j = 1:size(bounds_2,2)
            p(i+1) = p(i+1) + exp(-g2_k(j,:) * lambda) * bounds_2(i,j);
        end
    end
    
    p = (exp(-1-mu) * p) - cns;

end

% All combinations of elements.
function [m,i] = combn(v,n)

    if ((fix(n) ~= n) || (n < 1) || (numel(n) ~= 1))
        error('Parameter N must be a scalar positive integer.');
    end

    if (isempty(v))
        m = [];
        i = [];
    elseif (n == 1)
        m = v(:); 
        i = (1:numel(v)).';
    else
        i = combn_local(1:numel(v),n);
        m = v(i);
    end
    
    function y = combn_local(v,n)

        if (n > 1)
            [y{n:-1:1}] = ndgrid(v);
            y = reshape(cat(n+1,y{:}),[],n);
        else
            y = v(:);
        end

    end
    
end

% Multivariate normal cumulative distribution function.
function y = mvncdf2(c,lb,ub)

    persistent options;

    if (isempty(options))
        options = optimset(optimset(@fsolve),'Algorithm','trust-region-dogleg','Diagnostics','off','Display','off','Jacobian','on');
    end
    
    n = size(c,1);

    [cp,lb,ub] = cholperm(n,c,lb,ub);
    d = diag(cp);

    if any(d < eps())
        y = NaN;
        return;
    end

    lb = lb ./ d;
    ub = ub ./ d;
    cp = (cp ./ repmat(d,1,n)) - eye(n);

    [sol,~,exitflag] = fsolve(@(x)gradpsi(x,cp,lb,ub),zeros(2 * (n - 1),1),options);

    if (exitflag ~= 1)
        y = NaN;
        return;
    end

    x = sol(1:(n - 1));
    x(n) = 0;
    x = x(:);
    
    mu = sol(n:((2 * n) - 2));
    mu(n) = 0;
    mu = mu(:);
    
    c = cp * x;
    lb = lb - mu - c;
    ub = ub - mu - c;

    y = exp(sum(lnpr(lb,ub) + (0.5 * mu.^2) - (x .* mu)));

end

function [cp,l,u] = cholperm(n,c,l,u)

    s2p = sqrt(2 * pi());

    cp = zeros(n,n);
    z = zeros(n,1);

    for j = 1:n
        j_seq = 1:(j - 1);
        jn_seq = j:n;
        j1n_seq = (j + 1):n;

        cp_off = cp(jn_seq,j_seq);
        z_off = z(j_seq);
        cpz = cp_off * z_off;

        d = diag(c);
        s = d(jn_seq) - sum(cp_off.^2,2);
        s(s < 0) = eps();
        s = sqrt(s);

        lt = (l(jn_seq) - cpz) ./ s;
        ut = (u(jn_seq) - cpz) ./ s;

        p = Inf(n,1);
        p(jn_seq) = lnpr(lt,ut);

        [~,k] = min(p);
        jk = [j k];
        kj = [k j];

        c(jk,:) = c(kj,:);
        c(:,jk) = c(:,kj);

        cp(jk,:) = cp(kj,:);
        l(jk) = l(kj);
        u(jk) = u(kj);

        s = c(j,j) - sum(cp(j,j_seq).^2);
        s(s < 0) = eps();

        cp(j,j) = sqrt(s);
        cp(j1n_seq,j) = (c(j1n_seq,j) - (cp(j1n_seq,j_seq) * (cp(j,j_seq)).')) / cp(j,j);

        cp_jj = cp(j,j);
        cpz = cp(j,j_seq) * z(j_seq);
        lt = (l(j) - cpz) / cp_jj;
        ut = (u(j) - cpz) / cp_jj;

        w = lnpr(lt,ut);
        z(j) = (exp((-0.5 * lt.^2) - w) - exp((-0.5 * ut.^2) - w)) / s2p;
    end

end

function [g,j] = gradpsi(y,L,l,u)

    d = length(u);
    d_seq = 1:(d - 1);

    x = zeros(d,1);
    x(d_seq) = y(d_seq);

    mu = zeros(d,1);
    mu(d_seq) = y(d:end);

    c = zeros(d,1);
    c(2:d) = L(2:d,:) * x;

    lt = l - mu - c;
    ut = u - mu - c;

    w = lnpr(lt,ut);
    pd = sqrt(2 * pi());
    pl = exp((-0.5 * lt.^2) - w) / pd;
    pu = exp((-0.5 * ut.^2) - w) / pd;
    p = pl - pu;

    dfdx = -mu(d_seq) + (p.' * L(:,d_seq)).';
    dfdm = mu - x + p;
    g = [dfdx; dfdm(d_seq)];

    lt(isinf(lt)) = 0;
    ut(isinf(ut)) = 0;

    dp = -p.^2 + (lt .* pl) - (ut .* pu);
    dl = repmat(dp,1,d) .* L;

    mx = -eye(d) + dl;
    mx = mx(d_seq,d_seq);
    
    xx = L.' * dl;
    xx = xx(d_seq,d_seq);

    j = [xx mx.'; mx diag(1 + dp(d_seq))];

end

function p = lnpr(a,b)

    p = zeros(size(a));

    a_indices = a > 0;
    
    if (any(a_indices))
        x = a(a_indices);
        pa = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));
        
        x = b(a_indices);
        pb = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));

        p(a_indices) = pa + log1p(-exp(pb - pa));
    end

    b_indices = b < 0;

    if (any(b_indices))
        x = -a(b_indices);
        pa = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));

        x = -b(b_indices);
        pb = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));

        p(b_indices) = pb + log1p(-exp(pa - pb));
    end

    indices = ~a_indices & ~b_indices;

    if (any(indices))
        pa = erfc(-a(indices) / sqrt(2)) / 2;
        pb = erfc(b(indices) / sqrt(2)) / 2;
        p(indices) = log1p(-pa - pb);
    end

end
```

Comment: 1) You should present a minimal reproducible problem. If the issue is in the parfor loop cut out all stuff not required for this loop.
2) You should provide comments/explanations, e.g. what is mvncdf2 doing exactly?
3) The main issue seems to be the exponential explosion of octants (i.e. "k=2^n"). If every octant calculation is really necessary you are in trouble. But your CDF seems to contain many 0s,1s and +/-Infs. For these values a multivariate normal computation simplifies. You should check those rules and whether you can apply them. And is there any symmetry you can use?

Comment: 1) Ok, I can review the snippet but I thought it could have been useful to provide the full model just to give a better idea of what I'm working on. 2) MVNCDF2 is a function to compute multivariate normal cumulative distribution, it's just a faster implementation than the MATLAB built-in one (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvncdf.html). 3) Infs are just distribution bounds... all the combinations of [-Inf DT] and [DT Inf] must be computed for every observation.

Comment: No clues about potential symmetries. All I know is that the values of vector "bounds_1", once computed, must sum to 1 and I don't know if this is exploitable. I'm wondering if there are approximation algorithms, monte carlo approaches or dimensional reduction methodologies I could exploit.

Answer (score 2):

After stepping through your code a bit it seems as if you would like to calculate $\text{mvncdf}(lb, ub)$ where $lb$ is a $n$-vector which runs through all combinations of either a datapoint $dts_i$ or $-\infty$ and $ub$ runs through combinations of either $dts_i$ or $\infty$.

Furthermore your multivariate normal has covariance matrix $c$ equal to the identity matrix. This means the normal margins are uncorrelated, hence independent.

**First simplification:**

You do not need to solve a multivariate problem, since in your case
$$ \text{mvncdf}(lb,ub) = \prod_{i=1}^n \text{normcdf}(lb_i, ub_i).$$

where $\text{normcdf}$ is the CDF of the univariate standard normal.

**Second simplification:**

Since $\text{normcdf}(-\infty,\infty)=1$ you can ignore all those terms in the product.

**Third Simplification:**

You can use that $\text{normcdf}(-\infty, dts_i) = 1 - \text{normcdf}(dts_i, \infty).$

In total it seems all you have to do is multiply appropriate combinations of $z_i = \text{normcdf}(-\infty, dts_i)$ and $1- z_i$. This should be perfectly doable for 1048576 combinations and even a few more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, in the example I used an identity matrix. Unfortunately, the model must be capable of handling correlated time-series as well. I would say that in the most cases, the covariance matrix will NOT be identity. I'm sorry for this, I should have probably specified it before.